# How to join tables of multiple events while preserving information?

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge

So I have a use case where I have a few tables with different types of events in a time series, plus another table with base information. The events are of different types with different columns, for example an event of "marriage" could have the columns "husband name" and "wife name", and a table of events on "jobs" can have columns of "hired on" and "fired on" but can also have "husband name". The base info table is not time series data, and has stuff like "case ID" and "city of case".

The goal would be to 1. have all the different time series tables in one table with all possible columns, wherever there's no data in a column it's okay to have NaN. And 2. All entries in the time series should have all available data from the base data table.

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['Dave', 1,'call'], ['Josh', 2, 'rejection'], ['Greg', 3,'call']]), columns=['husband name', 'casenum', 'event'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['Dave', 'Mona', 1, 'new lamp'], ['Max', 'Lisa',1, 'big increase'],['Pete', 'Esther',3,'call'], ['Josh', 'Moana', 2, 'delivery']]), columns=['husband name','wife name','casenum', 'event'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 'new york'],[3,'old york'], [2, 'york']]), columns=['casenum','city'])
```

I'm trying a concat:

```
concat = pd.concat([df, df2, df3])
```

[image]

This doesn't work, because we already know that for case num 1 the city is 'new york'

I'm trying a join:

```
innerjoin = pd.merge(df, df2, on='casenum', how='inner')
innerjoin = pd.merge(innerjoin, df3, on='casenum', how='inner')
```

[image]

This also isn't right, as I want to have a record of *all* the events from both tables. Also, interestingly enough, the result is the same for both inner and outer joins on the dummy data, however, on my actual data an *inner* join will result in *more* rows than the sum of both the event tables, which I don't quite understand.

Basically, my desired outcome would be:

```
    husband name    casenum   event        wife name    city
0   Dave            1         call         NaN          new york
1   Josh            2         rejection    NaN          york
2   Greg            3         call         NaN          old york
0   Dave            1         new lamp     Mona         new york
1   Max             1         big increase Lisa         new york
2   Pete            3         call         Esther       old york
3   Josh            2         delivery     Moana        york
```

I've tried inner joins, outer joins, concats, none seem to work. Maybe I'm just too tired, but what do I need to do to get this output? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can merge twice with outer option:

```
(df.merge(df2,on=['husband name', 'casenum', 'event'], how='outer')
   .merge(df3, on='casenum')
)
```

Output:

```
  husband name casenum         event wife name      city
0         Dave       1          call       NaN  new york
1         Dave       1      new lamp      Mona  new york
2          Max       1  big increase      Lisa  new york
3         Josh       2     rejection       NaN      york
4         Josh       2      delivery     Moana      york
5         Greg       3          call       NaN  old york
6         Pete       3          call    Esther  old york
```